# Swift - cannot set json model type as UserDefault

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to store *PlayersDetails* (which is json model) array into UserDefaults.

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton, player: PlayerDetails){
    
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    var favoritePlayers = [PlayerDetails]()

    print(favoritePlayers.count)

    userDefaults.set(sender.isSelected, forKey: "playerFavorite\(player.player.name ?? "")")
    
    if sender.isSelected {
        
        favoritePlayers.append(player)
        userDefaults.set(favoritePlayers, forKey: "players")
    }
}
```

PlayerDetails:

```
public struct PlayerDetails: Codable {

public let player: PlayerInfo
public let statistics: [PlayerStatistics]

}
```

But when I am trying to get stored data I am getting *Attempt to set a non-property-list object as an NSUserDefaults* error.

I tried to store data as *[String]* and as *[Data]*, but value is *nil*

Is there any valid way I can store data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't store JSON model array into UserDefaults. You need to encode the model into `Data` type and then store it in UserDefaults. With the help of `JSONEncoder()` and `JSONDecoder()` you can achieve this.

Try this:

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton, player: PlayerDetails){
    
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    var favoritePlayers = [PlayerDetails]()

    print(favoritePlayers.count)

    UserDefaults.set(sender.isSelected, forKey: "playerFavorite\(player.player.name ?? "")")
    
    if sender.isSelected {       
        favoritePlayers.append(player)
        do {
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            let favoritePlayersData = try encoder.encode(favoritePlayers)
            UserDefaults.set(favoritePlayersData, forKey: "players")
        } catch {
            print("Unable to Encode Favorite Players (\(error))")
        }
    }
}
```

Once you are able to store the array data in UserDefaults you can read it by decoding it.

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "players") {
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let favoritePlayers = try decoder.decode(PlayerDetails.self, from: data)
        print(favoritePlayers.count)
    } catch {
        print("Unable to Decode Favorite Players (\(error))")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Extention

```
extension UserDefaults {
        func set<T: Encodable>(encodable: T, forKey key: String) {
            if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(encodable) {
                set(data, forKey: key)
            }
        }
    
        func value<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: String) -> T? {
            if let data = object(forKey: key) as? Data,
                let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(type, from: data) {
                return value
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
```

User Like This to Sava Model

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(encodable: Model, forKey: "Key Here")
```

Get Data Like This

```
let user = UserDefaults.standard.value(Model.self, forKey: "Same Key Here")
```